# Have two links in the same file with different style

Tags: html

I want to have 2 different link in the same html file and every link have different style. However I can make the second link to be as I want. Why I can't make it?

Here it is the code I use to make it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
        a.link1{
        }
        a.link1:hover{
            background-color: #B2FF99; 
        }
        a.link1:active{
            color: green;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a.link1:visited{
            background-color: #FFFF85;

        a.link2, a.link2:visited {
            display: block;
        }

        a.link2:hover, a.link2:active {
            background-color: #7A991A;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
<a href="www.google.com" class="class1"> Google </a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="class2">Stackoverflow</a>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a>` tags have the classes `class1` and `class2`, but the CSS refers to `link1` and `link2`. You probably want something like:

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="link1"> Google </a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="link2">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 <a href="www.google.com" class="link1"> Google </a>
 <a href="www.stackoverflow.com" class="link2">Stackoverflow</a>
```